# How can i validate if all the objects are created successfully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this piece of controller code, to create an new Task, in the middle of that execution, i need to create several new object at the intermediate table called 'subTasks'

```
Task_ids.each do |task_id|

        created = Subtask.create(task_id: task_id)

end
```

i want to validate if all the subtask was success created or no, i need catch an error at the application_controller

its possible to validate that?

Comment: if `task_id` is an integer, then `Subtask.create(task_id)` will not create a persisted object, you need to pass a hash to the create method

Comment: @LesNightingill only i want to catch that error from aplication_controller

Comment: you should not be catching errors in the application controller. Also you need to pass a hash to the create method, not an integer, else it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    Task_ids.each do |task_id|
      created = Subtask.create(task_id)
    end
  end
  puts "All subtasks were created successfully without any errors."
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  puts "Validation error occurred: #{e.message}"
rescue => e
  puts "An unexpected error occurred: #{e.message}"
end
```

The `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` method is used to wrap the creation of subtasks within a transaction block. This ensures that all subtask creations are treated as a single unit of work. If any `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` error occurs during the creation, the transaction will be automatically rolled back, and the exception will be caught in the first `rescue` block.

You can handle the validation error, such as displaying an error message or logging the error, within the first rescue block. Additionally, you can use the second rescue block to catch any other unexpected errors and handle them accordingly.

By using transactions in Ruby on Rails, you can ensure the atomicity of your subtask creations and handle any errors that may occur during the process.

Comment: only the `create!` method will raise an exception if the record is invalid